# Wacom Intuos Pro (tablet) not working with Blender on OSX

Tags: modeling, sculpting

My Wacom Intuos Pro isn't working when I try to use it in Blender. I can move the cursor of the computer but not Blender's cursor.

How can I debug or provide more information?

Outside of blender, it seems like I can move the cursor but not click with it.

I am on OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is: go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > check "WacomTabletDriver".